# What is this spider spinning a bright green web?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Here is the picture of it I took with my phone while I was out working:

[image]

Here is a close up:

[image]

Location: Texas (winter).

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a close up image of the critter?

Comment: Here are close ups on the so called critter (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pUjL.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tWee.jpg)

Comment: As beautiful as they are one both dont spin weds at all and he is so hard to get a close up picture of because he is smaller then a fingernail + it's a phone camera so don't expect great quality as long as I lives never have I seen a spider spin a Wed other then the color white

Answer (score 2):

Your image is not the best one, but this is probably the [Magnolia green jumper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyssomanes_viridis), *Lyssomanes viridis*.

Here is a better image of it for comparison:

[image]

It also matches your location. According to the Wikipedia page linked above,

> the species is native to the Southeastern United States plus Texas, and as far north as Maryland.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Green Lynx Spider (*Peucetia viridans*) [here](http://www.spiders.us/species/peucetia-viridans/).  The spots on the body look similar.  If the legs are similar this is a good candidate.  It's hard to tell by the photos if this is it or not, but it may help.

[image]

Source: http://www.spiders.us/species/peucetia-viridans/

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with the jumping spider, for two reasons - first, the Lynx Spiders make a normal brown egg sac, and second, there is a strikingly similar jumping spider in Australia, called Mopsus mormon, that also makes a green egg sac (although, to be fair, it's the eggs that look green rather than the silk..)
http://malcolmtattersall.com.au/wp/2015/10/mopsus-mormon-mummy/[image]